# Is their a way to decrease a number? 10/7/20 - 3/5/21 *update*

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

**What I tried to do is decrease 1000 to 900 but instead it  would give 999 not 900 an then it would put the 900 above the the text.

```
     Cone_head Casted The cone of time & Cone of shield 
     4
    you regain 5 slots
    900
    you lost 999 of your health 
    expericance: 2.7
```

**Here's the code:**

```
 _Player_Health = Player_Health = 1000; 

  damage = 100;

      

 if (Chance > 99)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(Player_Health - damage);
        System.Console.WriteLine(Player_Health);
        Player_Health--;
        System.Console.WriteLine("you lost "+ Player_Health + "  of your health");   
        string a = Convert.ToString(Player_Health);
        
    } else
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Miss!, next player turn");
        c = Convert.ToInt16(Player_Health);
    }




 static void Main(string[] args)
{

    int Player_Health = 1000;
    Conehead_Wizzard wizzard = new Conehead_Wizzard("Cone_Head ", "The Cone of time &" + " Cone of shield", Player_Health);

}
```

[player_Health - b prints out this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yH0US.png)

Comment: it is really hard to understand what you want. do you want to reduce the health by "b" and show by how much the health was reduced in the console? Then replace "Player_Health" with "b" in the Console.WriteLine(...)

Comment: @Blechdose I added more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing too much code to make people understand what you want. it is not even possible to compile what you showed. Do you want to do something like that:

```
damage = 100;

if (Chance > 99)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Health before taking damage: " + Player_Health);
    Player_Health -= damage;
    System.Console.WriteLine("you lost "+ damage + "  of your health");   
    System.Console.WriteLine("You have " + Player_Health + " health left");   
    string a = Convert.ToString(Player_Health);
    
} else
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Miss!, next player turn");
    c = Convert.ToInt16(Player_Health);
}
```

Comment: yes! That's what I was looking for! THANK YOU ;]